# ¿Como poner una id a un tr si es que no tiene una id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

(No tengo claro que titulo poner en la pregunta si alguien tiene una mejor por favor me avisa)

Buenas tardes lo que quiero hacer es poner una id diferente a todos los tr que no cuenten con una.

E podido insertar ID a los tr de la tabla pero le pone la misma ID a todas (Pongan inspeccionar código ahí se ve que todas tienen  "id=1")
e puesto un if para que solo ponga la id a aquellos tr que no tengan una  pero 
solo funciona en el primer tr .

Alguien sabe como hacer para que en el for que tengo verifique uno por uno a los tr viendo si la primera no tiene id  pues solo a ese le pone una id y luego pase a verificar a la otra y así sucesivamente sin afectar a las demás filas.

O en todo caso hay alguna forma de que datatable ponga una id o un contador a los tr ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  valor = 7;
  for (var i = 1; i <= valor; i++) {

    if ($("table tbody tr").attr('id')) {

    } else {

      $("table tbody tr").attr('id', i);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" style="width: 100%;" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 50px;max-width: 50px;min-width: 50px;">ITEM</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;max-width: 250px;min-width: 250px;">APELLIDOS Y NOMBRES</th>
      <th style="width: 150px;max-width: 150px;min-width: 150px;">DNI</th>
      <th style="width: 150px;max-width: 150px;min-width: 150px;">CARGO</th>
      <th style="width: 150px;max-width: 150px;min-width: 150px;">ÁREA</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td>54678912</td>
      <td>cargo</td>
      <td>area</td>
    </tr>

    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Carlos</td>
      <td>1245678</td>
      <td>cargo</td>
      <td>area</td>
    </tr>

    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Pedro</td>
      <td>45678932</td>
      <td>cargo</td>
      <td>area</td>
    </tr>

    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Jorge</td>
      <td>87654231</td>
      <td>cargo</td>
      <td>area</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el selector devuelve todas las trs.  La solucion es iterar por todas las trs y agregar el id.  Puedes usar jQuery's `$.each` asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var trs = $("table tbody tr");
    $.each(trs, function(i, tr) {
      if (!$(tr).attr('id')) {    
        $(tr).attr('id', i + 1);
      }
    });  
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" style="width: 100%;" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 50px;max-width: 50px;min-width: 50px;">ITEM</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;max-width: 250px;min-width: 250px;">APELLIDOS Y NOMBRES</th>
      <th style="width: 150px;max-width: 150px;min-width: 150px;">DNI</th>
      <th style="width: 150px;max-width: 150px;min-width: 150px;">CARGO</th>
      <th style="width: 150px;max-width: 150px;min-width: 150px;">ÁREA</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td>54678912</td>
      <td>cargo</td>
      <td>area</td>
    </tr>

    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Carlos</td>
      <td>1245678</td>
      <td>cargo</td>
      <td>area</td>
    </tr>

    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Pedro</td>
      <td>45678932</td>
      <td>cargo</td>
      <td>area</td>
    </tr>

    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Jorge</td>
      <td>87654231</td>
      <td>cargo</td>
      <td>area</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```